# Android emulator fails on testing

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, sms, emulation

So i am making sms application, and am trying to add some intent filter to appear "Complete action using" dialog box. Everything seems to be fine but on emulator it does not appear (on real phone everything works ). So where could be a problem?

Comment: Probably in your code. Can we see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is showing on phones but not in the emulator, I often find this is because the android application bridge has got itself stuck.

Try killing adb.exe in task manager, you should then get "Failed to connect" errors in eclipse (if you are using it!) after the 12th error it will reload the adb. From then your app should load.

It's a strange problem that I have had only the first time an app is installed to the emulator. Also doesn't happen with Jelly Bean emulators!